# JavaScript Function to Post clicking checkbox keeps multiplying

Tags: javascript, ajax

This code its working okay but every time that I click on the checkbox it sends 1 post, then 2 posts, then 4 posts, then 8 posts etc.. to "insert.php". How can I prevent this error?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submiter').click(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log('checked ' + $(this).val());

        $.ajax({
          url: "insert.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            test1: $(this).val()
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ajax Jquery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" value="PHP" id="submiter" />PHP <br />
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: every click is adding a new 'onchange' listener to your input, thats why it is growing

Comment: You have 2 event handlers nested. First the click, then the change. Since the change is inside the click, it keeps on adding more and more change event handlers on every click.

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you have 1 handler for your input, an `onclick` handler.

When clicked, it adds an `onchange` listener to same element, from now on, you have 2 listeners for your input.

The next click, it adds one more `onchange` listener, and so on...

Do you really need an `onclick` listener? Maybe just the `onchange` isn't sufficient? See below code (I removed ajax part to avoid requests in this example)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submiter").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      console.log('checked ' + $(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="PHP" id="submiter" />PHP <br />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: It honestly took me sec to see it myself at first, so GG! +1 from me :)